# SQL Server - Improving linq queries performance and dealing Execution Timeout Expired error

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a SQL Server data base which is accessed by C# code using Entity. 3 of the DB tables are having more than a million records. I have set indexes for these tables for better performance of queries (Linq). Still my queries takes time especially when the larger tables are involved.
And sometimes I get "Execution Timeout Expired" error. I can get rid the error by increasing the TimeOut but I want better ptions.

I was Googling and found that executing "exec sp_updatestats" and "dbcc freeproccache" statements on daily basis keep queries fast.
I have 2 questions

1. Is this safe to use "exec sp_updatestats" and "dbcc freeproccache" on daily basis?
2. How can I speed up my Linq queries for tables which are larger (million plus rows).
3. If I use store procedures instead of Linq queries then would that give me better results?

[[ Edit Starts //Added Query below ]]

A sample Linq Query (Sales having million+ records),

```cs
var Query = DbContext.Sales
    .Where(w =>
        (w.IsOpen != null ? w.IsOpen.Value : false) &&
        (w.Deleted != null ? !w.Deleted.Value : false) &&
        (w.Status.Trim().ToLower() != "archive") &&
        (w.Status.Trim().ToLower() != "lost") &&
        (OwnerId != 0 ? w.BfoUserId == OwnerId : true) &&
        (SalesAgent != "" ? w.SalesAgent == SalesAgent : true) && 
        SalesIdsByStartDateEndDate.Contains(w.JobOrderId)
    )
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.DateAdded)
    .ToList();
```

[[ Edit Ends //Added Query above ]]

Comment: Please provide an example of your queries, it's impossible to suggest how they could be sped up otherwise

Comment: @RobKite Ok, Editing my question. Meanwhile if you can please answer the "Is this safe to use "exec sp_updatestats" and "dbcc freeproccache" on daily basis?"   ?

Comment: `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` throws away *all* execution plans in *all* databases and forces everything to be recompiled. This is a global solution to a local problem, and may be very detrimental on a busy production server. If this "solves" your problems, your real problem is things like statistics going out of date too frequently and parameter sniffing causing incorrect estimates. These problems have targeted solutions; `FREEPROCCACHE` can actually make it *worse* by allowing for more opportunities for a "bad" plan to sneak in. There's no silver bullet for optimizing.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank You! I will not be using  DBCC FREEPROCCACHE. What about "exec sp_updatestats" ? If I execute this midnight (when least traffic is on website)

Comment: Regularly updating statistics may help *if* your problem is statistics being out of date, which is a big "if". The first step in investigating performance problems is getting the execution plans of the badly performing queries, then looking at what causes the bad plans: improper indexing, a query that has conditions that indexes can't speed up, parameter sniffing, out-of-date statistics... Updating statistics once a day won't hurt, but it may not help either.

Comment: perhaps you can consider specifying the index to be used if the execution plan is being generated wrong for a query (using index hints). LINQ doesn't support using index hints so you would have to either execute raw sql or use a stored procedure and use LINQ to call it. a more healthy solution however, would be to find the root of the problem (why is execution plan being generated wrong?)

Comment: All those null checks, trims and lowercasing force the database to scan the entire table. Remove all of them. Just `w.IsOpen` is enough to include only values that have 1/true in the `IsOpen` field. In SQL Server collations are usually case-insensitive which means you can write just `w.Status != 'archive'` or even better `w.Status NOT IN ('archive','lost')`. That can be translated to `w=> !ignoreValues.Contains(w.Status)`. LINQ will convert that to the equivalent `NOT IN (...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in that query that prevent the use of indexes. This has little to do with statistics.

The query can be simplified to this,

```
var Query = DbContext.Sales
    .Where(w =>
        w.IsOpen &&
        !w.Deleted &&
        skipStatuses.Contains(w.Status) &&
        SalesIdsByStartDateEndDate.Contains(w.JobOrderId)
    );

if(OwnerId!=0)
{
    query = query.Where(w=>w.BfoUserId == OwnerId);
}
if(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(SalesAgent))
{
    query = query.Where(w=>w.SalesAgent == SalesAgent);
}
```

This will allow the use of indexes on the `Status` and `JobOrderId` fields and possibly `IsOpen` and `Deleted` as well. SQL Server doesn't allow indexing `bit` fields as they aren't very selective. If the table uses integer fields instead of `bit` then SQL Server may decide to use any covering indexes if the data statistics justify it

You can use the [IQueryable.ToQueryString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-7.0) extension method to get the actual query and inspect its execution plan.

**Explanation**

The clause

```
w.IsOpen != null ? w.IsOpen.Value : false
```

Will be translated to

```
WHERE IIF(IsOpen IS NULL,1,0) =1
```

This can't be accelerated by any indexes because the server needs the result of the `IIF(IsOpen IS NULL,1,0)` expression to decide what to filter. This will force a full table scan.

`w.IsOpen` alone or `w.IsOpen ==true` would be translated to `IsOpen =0` which *could* use indexes. SQL Server doesn't allow indexes on `bit` fields though, although these *can* be used in filtered indexes.

Second, `w.Status.Trim().ToLower()`  will be translated to `TOLOWER(TRIM(Status))` once again preventing the use of indexes.

Lowercasing isn't necessary in general, because the common SQL Server collations are case-*in*sensitive. As for trimming, it's up to the application to ensure the data is clean, to allow indexing.

The LINQ query should simplified to :

```
var skipStatuses=new[]{"archive","lost"};

var Query = DbContext.Sales
    .Where(w =>
        w.IsOpen &&
        !w.Deleted &&
        skipStatuses.Contains(w.Status) &&
        w.BfoUserId == OwnerId  &&
        w.SalesAgent == SalesAgent  && 
        SalesIdsByStartDateEndDate.Contains(w.JobOrderId)
    )
```

There's no need for catch-all expressions like `(OwnerId != 0 ? w.BfoUserId == OwnerId : true)` either. Chaining `.Where` clauses is essentially the same as combining them with `AND`. The application code can inspect the parameter values and only include a filter if it's needed. For example :

```
var Query = DbContext.Sales
    .Where(w =>
        w.IsOpen &&
        !w.Deleted &&
        skipStatuses.Contains(w.Status) &&
        SalesIdsByStartDateEndDate.Contains(w.JobOrderId)
    );

if(OwnerId!=0)
{
    query = query.Where(w=>w.BfoUserId == OwnerId);
}
if(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(SalesAgent))
{
    query = query.Where(w=>w.SalesAgent == SalesAgent);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If it was me I would create a stored procedure and you can then see the execution plan yourself for the query. Then you can make a more informed decision as to whether it is best to replace the LINQ query with it. You wont have to worry about nulls so much for fields actually specified in your where. Also you can ensure your datatypes are the same for the selection and the table. My suspicion is with that contains though and that would be better done in a SP I think.

Comment: You don't need a stored procedure to get the actual SQL query and check its execution plan. Stored procedures won't make bad queries run faster. `You wont have to worry about nulls so much for fields actually specified in your where. ` quite the opposite, those null checks will appear in SQL as extra operations that may result in table scans.

Comment: If you specify the Boolean in the query you wont get nulls back is what I meant. Also I didnt say it would make it run faster i just said you could then make an informed decision once you can see the bottleneck in the execution plan.

Comment: You don't need a stored procedure to see the execution plan. You can get it from EF Core directly, SQL Server Extended Events, SQL Server Profiler and even Activity Monitor. And that `Contains` is actually a *good* thing, because it's translated to `w.JobOrderId IN (@id1, @id2, @id3)`

Comment: you don't but it takes a couple of minutes to do. Seems you just want to be argumentative. What do you think it is then?

Comment: Why would you though? What's said here is: there are enough tools to analyze queries running against the database. Why would you first create a stored procedure? You could even create something that behaves differently.